Date as number/text in YYYYMMDD format, but Excel won't format?
I'm working with a JSON dataset that presents dates as numbers in a column like so: 20190611, meaning it should be 2019-06-11. What can I do to get Excel to format these dates? Normal formatting doesn't seem to work. Or do I need to insert hyphens in the right locations? If so, any pointers on that?

left(), mid(), right() and & or concatenate()
